# Angular2 and social sharing crawlers

Tags: javascript, facebook, angular

As far as I understood, the social crawlers like the one of Facebook do not evaluate Javascript, therefore when you use Angular 1, if you wanted to let any pages of your site being properly shared on Facebook, you would have use services like prerender.io or follow tutorials like the following to implement the sharing of the content and not not rendered tags.

- [Enable Rich Social Sharing in Your AngularJS
  App](http://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/171/enable-rich-social-sharing-in-your-angularjs-app)
- [How to support social sharing for AngularJS apps using Facebooks
  Open Graph
  tags](https://rck.ms/angular-handlebars-open-graph-facebook-share/)

I'm asking myself if that side effect is maybe solved straight forward in Angular 2? Or do these solutions are still the one to apply?

Comment: [Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/) could be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thx for the idea gonna have a look. My site is directly served from nginx so I should check if universal is also applicable in that situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the advice of @federico-p and implemented a `Angular universal` app

Therefore I based my implementation on the following starter-app:

https://github.com/angular/universal-starter